# How to remove beamer section buttons in CambridgeUS

Tags: beamer, section-titles, subsection

I want more space to write sentences, so I need to delete the link button of the sections (black box). However, I need to keep the section title, only delete the black box area. How can I do this? thanks for help.

[image]

```
\documentclass[utf8,7.875pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\section{1}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
\title{ccc}
\end{frame}

\section{\textbf{I.} }
\subsection{\textbf{A.} }
\begin{frame}
\begin{tiny}
ccc
\end{tiny}
\end{frame}

\subsection{\textbf{B.}}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tiny}
ccc
\end{tiny}
\end{frame}

\subsection{\textbf{B.} }
\begin{frame}
\begin{tiny}
\begin{itemize}
\item[]
\begin{itemize}
\item{\textbf{(b).}} 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{tiny}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Does it help if you comment out `\useoutertheme{miniframes}` or use another theme, probably `infolines` suits you most?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Οὖτις said in their comment, if you don't want miniframes, don't load the `miniframe` outer theme.

However you could also save a lot of space by using the `compress` class option. This will show all the miniframes in a single line instead of spreading them out over multiple lines.

Some other comments about your code:

- there is no such thing as an `7.875pt` option in beamer
- the `utf8` is no longer useful with current latex
- you don't need to load the `etoolbox` package, beamer does this automatically.
- the syntax `\begin{tiny}...\end{tiny}` does not make much sense. You should rather use `{\tiny .... }` (make sure to leave an empty line after `\begin{frame}` so this won't be interpreted as frame title...)
- using `\title` does not make that much sense if you don't also use `\maketitle` somewhere. I would place `\title{...}` in the preamble so that it can be picked up to create meaningful pdf meta data
- instead of manually adjusting the font for every (sub-)section, you could set the respective beamer fonts

---

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bm}

\title{ccc}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{series=\itshape}

\begin{document}

\section{1}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{I.}
\subsection{A.}
\begin{frame}

{\tiny
ccc
}
\end{frame}

\subsection{B.}
\begin{frame}

{\tiny
ccc
}
\end{frame}

\subsection{B.}
\begin{frame}

{\tiny
\begin{itemize}
\item[]
\begin{itemize}
\item{\textbf{(b).}} 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```